# Showing JSON format in C3 (D3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js, c3.js

How to show data in C3 (or D3) graph based on this JSON format:

```
[{"Type":"Dog","Number":13},{"Type":"Cat","Number":21}]
```

Here is angular controller with data from JSON and the problem is in defining `keys` atribute. I'm a litle bit confused about merging Type with Number.. Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ObCVxJNy3ehl0YvS0DIH?p=preview)

```
angular.module('c3example', [])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope){
     d3.json('/chartData.json', function(err, data){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        $scope.data = data;

        $scope.chart_types = c3.generate({
            bindto: d3.select('#chart'),
            size: {
                weight: 640,
                height: 480
            },
            data: {
                json: $scope.data,
                keys: {
                    value: ['Dog', 'Cat'],
                },
                type: 'bar'
             },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.5 // 
            }
        }
        });
    });
  })
```

And binding in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body ng-app="c3example" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="chart" build-chart></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the plunker doesn't even load the json

Comment: Thanks Tamas, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your keys enumeration Array have to match the JSON keys that contains the values :

Replace :

```
[{"Type":"Dog","Number":13},{"Type":"Cat","Number":21}]
```

By :

```
[{"Dog":13, "Cat":21}, {"Dog":42, "Cat":31}, ...]
```

Note : You may consider using lowercase keys to avoid errors.

**EDIT :** Here is how your controller should look like

```
angular.module('c3example', [])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('chartData.json')    // Use angular $http instead of d3.json to use promise chaining
      .then(function ( json ) {
        $scope.data = formatData(json.data);  // format received data

        // generate chart
        $scope.chart_types = c3.generate({
          bindto: d3.select('#chart'),
          size: {
            weight: 640,
            height: 480
          },
          data: {
            json: $scope.data,
            keys: {
              value: ['Dog', 'Cat'],
            },
            type: 'bar'
          },
          bar: {
            width: {
              ratio: 0.5 
            }
          }
        });
      },
      function ( err ) {
        console.log(err);   // log if an error occurs
      });

    // function that take you raw data into input and return a c3 compatible array
    function formatData ( json ) {
      var formattedData = [],
          object        = {};

      // fill object with data
      angular.forEach(json, function(row) {
        if (row.hasOwnProperty('Type') && row.hasOwnProperty('Number')) {
          this[row.Type] = row.Number;
        }
      },object);

      formattedData.push(object); // push c3 object in the array

      return formattedData;
    }
  })
```

Comment: That would be great, but I cannot change the data structure :(

Comment: hmm.. So you have to transform them before using it. I'll update my answer once I figure out how.